# change ids and classes of html text with jquery on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my situation:

```
<div id="div1" class="divPhase">
    <div class="row margin-top-1">
        <div class="column">
            <label>Title Phase 1:</label>
            <textarea id="title-1" name="title-phase-1" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <label>Description Phase 1:</label>
            <textarea id="description-1" name="description-phase-1" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <a class="removeLink">Remove div1</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="divPhase">
    <div class="row margin-top-2">
        <div class="column">
            <label>Title Phase 2:</label>
            <textarea id="title-2" name="title-phase-2" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <label>Description Phase 2:</label>
            <textarea id="description-2" name="description-phase-2" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <a class="removeLink">Remove div2</a>
    </div>
</div>
....
....
and so on with div3, div4 etc.
```

As you can see, for each div (`div1`, `div2`, `div3`, and so on) I have a link which will remove its parent div with class `divPhase`.

Here is the code:

```
$(".removeLink").closest(".divPhase").remove();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an ascending ordered and contiguous list of divs even after removing some divs.

I'll try to be more clear. As of now if I have, let's say, 5 divs as the ones above (with these ids: `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, `div4` and `div5`) if I remove `div3` with the click on the link with class `removeLink` what I get is a list of 4 divs (`div1`, `div2`, `div4` and `div5`).

This list is not contiguous because between `div2` and `div4` we need `div3`. 
What I'd like to get is `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, `div4` (`div4` should become `div3` and `div5` should become).

Moreover I should achieve the same for the textarea's ids (`title-5` and `description-5` should become `title-4` and `description-4` while `title-4` and `description-4` should become `title-3` and `description-3`).

How do I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, would you be able to use something like `document.getElementsByClassName("column")` and access the array that results?

Comment: What are you using the IDs for that requires them to be contiguous?

Comment: @James This code comes from another person, and I've been told to not  modify ids and classes.

Comment: so you want the text inside each been updated too? or just the all id to be updated?

Comment: It would be easier to fix the other person's code so it doesn't care about ids, classnames, name attributes, and make the whole thing more generic, than it would be to create a function to renumber everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more elegant way to do it: trigger an event when the `.divPhase` is removed (`remove-row`), and attach an `updateIndexes` listener to it. In the body of this function you can change any attributes you like in a loop of all `.divPhase`'s.

**Note:** *although the below snippet works for this use case, if you find yourself often needing to add extra modifications per element/ attribute, you might want to consider a **data-first/ template** rendering solution, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), for a comprehensive list see [javascripting.com](http://www.javascripting.com/application-tools/templating/?sort=rating)*

```js
var removeEntry = function() {
  $('#rows').trigger('remove-row', [$(this).closest('.row').index()]);
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
};

var updateIndexes = function(e, index) {
  var selector = ':input, .divPhase';
  $('#rows').children().filter(function(i) {
    return i > index;
  }).each(function(i) {
    $(this).find(selector).add(this).each(function() {
      var displayIndex = (i + 1);
      if (this.className && this.className.length)
        this.className = this.className.slice(0, -1) + displayIndex;
      if (this.id && this.id.length)
        this.id = this.id.slice(0, -1) + displayIndex;
      if (this.name && this.name.length)
        this.name = this.name.slice(0, -1) + displayIndex;
      if (this.value && this.value.length)
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1) + displayIndex;
    });
  });
};

$('#rows').on('remove-row', updateIndexes);
$('.row a').on('click', removeEntry);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rows">
  <div class="row divPhase-1">
    <input type="text" name="title-1" id="title-1" value="value-1">
    <textarea name="desc-1" id="desc-1"></textarea>
    <a href="#desc-1-removed">Remove</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row divPhase-2">
    <input type="text" name="title-2" id="title-2" value="value-2">
    <textarea name="desc-2" id="desc-2"></textarea>
    <a href="#desc-2-removed">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop throught all the remaining `divPhase`, right after the removal on click... To re-number them.

So that is a big loop.
**I'm really unsure that this is usefull to do it.**
But here is how it can be done anyway.

```
$(".removeLink").on("click",function(){
  $(this).closest(".divPhase").remove();

  var divPhase = $(document).find(".divPhase");

  for(i=0;i<divPhase.length;i++){
    var j= i+1;
    divPhase.eq(i).attr("id","div"+j);

    // Row class
    var row = divPhase.eq(i).find(".row");
    row.attr("class","row margin-top-"+j);

    // Labels
    var labels = divPhase.eq(i).find("label");
    for(k=0;k<labels.length;k++){
      var labelHtml = labels.eq(k).html();
      labels.eq(k).html(labelHtml.substr(0,labelHtml.length-2)+j+":");
    }

    // Textareas
    var textareas = divPhase.eq(i).find("textarea");
    for(k=0;k<textareas.length;k++){
      var textareaId = textareas.eq(k).attr("id");
      textareas.eq(k).attr("id",textareaId.substr(0,textareaId.length-1)+j);

      var textareaName = textareas.eq(k).attr("name");
      textareas.eq(k).attr("name",textareaName.substr(0,textareaName.length-1)+j);
    }

    // Remove link
    var removeLinkHtml = divPhase.eq(i).find(".removeLink").html();
    divPhase.eq(i).find(".removeLink").html(removeLinkHtml.substr(0,removeLinkHtml.length-1)+j);
  }
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yXzdPp?editors=1010)